# Keep toggle and add class active with JQuery through pages refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used `onClick` function and when I click the functions `addClass` and toggle events get added to the function. Once when I activate the toggle and `addClass` and then refresh the page the `addClass` is getting removed and also the toggle events are running from the beginning. How to avoid the the removal of class and toggle function on page reload?

```
    jqry("#wrap").delegate('img.favourite', 'click', function() { 
      var toggle = $(this).data("toggleFlag") || false;
      var check_fav = jqry(this).hasClass('switcher-active');
      var id = jqry(this).attr('pid');
      if (!toggle && !check_fav) {
        jqry(this).addClass('switcher-active');
        alert("test1");
      } else {
        jqry(this).removeClass('switcher-active');
        alert("test2");
      }
      $(this).data("toggleFlag", !toggle);
    });


    <img class="favourite"  src="images/fav.png" alt="favourite" >
```

The above code is not working properly. I am getting `addClass('switcher-active')` active and getting the alert `test1` on first click and then `removeClass('switcher-active')` and alert `test2` on second click. But when I refresh the page after first click i.e after the `addClass('switcher-active')` active it must continue with `removeClass('switcher-active')` and alert `test2`. But on page refresh `addClass('switcher-active')` is inactive and alerted as `test1`. How to I get `test2` and `removeClass('switcher-active')` even after page refresh. How is this possible?

Comment: You want to use persistent storage client side as cookie/local or session storage, if i understand your issue

Comment: Check this link, it explains the cookie approach
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383742/keeping-toggled-class-after-page-refresh

Comment: Thank you!! The link was very helpful for my task.