# How can I make colour changes stick after refresh, or when I load a different page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, cookies, refresh

[Here is a folder with my two test pages](http://1drv.ms/1XOrjIK)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Keeping toggled class after page refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383742/keeping-toggled-class-after-page-refresh)

Comment: Your question title is ok, but the description contains link and no relevant code, so getting marked for close, so go through the "how to ask" section, upvoting to keep it open unless you add more description and code.

Answer (score 1):

Saving a variable in between sessions could be done using either Html5 Local Storage, or standard cookies.

Something to get you started.

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // What to do if LocalStorage is available
    // Store Method
    localStorage.color = "Red";
    // Retrieve Method
    document.body.style.background = localStorage.color;
} else {
    // Fallback method if LocalStorage is not available
    if ($.cookie('the_cookie', { path: '/' }) !== null) { 
       $.removeCookie("the_cookie", { path: '/' });
       $.cookie('color_cookie', 'blue', {expires:7, path:'/'}); 
    }
    document.body.style.background = $.cookie('color_cookie');
}
```